# Rhodesian Ridgeback Liver Nose Health

Tags: dogs, health, ears-nose-throat

I am interested in getting a Rhodesian Ridgeback. The registered breeder has both black and liver nosed pups. I would just like to know if there are any future health concerns I should know about if was to to get the liver nosed one's such as cancer etc.

Thanks